# Get or have or give a medical test

Tags: word-choice

Please imagine your doctor orders you some laboratory tests and you go to a pathology laboratory. The secretary asks you how can we help you? You respond:

> - I must **get** a (blood / urine / etc.) test.
> - I must **have** a (blood / urine / etc.) test.
> - I must **give** a (blood / urine / etc.) test.

As a test I examined blood in all three structures and got some [hits](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have%20a%20blood%20test%2C%20give%20a%20blood%20test%2C%20get%20a%20blood%20test&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Chave%20a%20blood%20test%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bhave%20a%20blood%20test%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHave%20a%20blood%20test%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgive%20a%20blood%20test%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cget%20a%20blood%20test%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bget%20a%20blood%20test%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BGet%20a%20blood%20test%3B%2Cc0), but the problem is that I don't know which one is natural in this case.

I would appreciate it if you could help me find the best choice here.

Comment: With Ngram results, it is safe to assume that if one of them occurs far more often than another, it will be the natural choice, and also safe to assume that if one of them is barely a blip, it shouldn't be used.  **give** is not a good choice. But  **get** or **have** are both natural.

Comment: Thank you for the help @TRomano. I knew it already, but you know well that Google Ngram as a tool doesn't have a sufficient intelligence to verify if the word I am searching is the right one in the meaning I am looking for too. Otherwise why should I have asked this question at all? ;)

Comment: "I am here for a blood test."

Answer (score 5):

As a patient, you would say:

> *I must **get** a (blood / urine / etc.) test*
>
> *I'm here for a (blood / urine / etc.) test*
>
> *I must **give** a (blood / urine / etc.) **sample** for a test.*

Comment: Another response can be "I have been told by my doctor to have my (blood/urine/etc.) tested"